# FakeItEasy: Return NULL returning fakeiteasy null object thus if statement always passes checks

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit, fluent-assertions, fakeiteasy

So i a xunit test method which goes into my Productorderservice to check if the a return value is null. However the returned object is never null as it returns a fakeiteasy null object even if i specify Fakeiteasy's .Returns method to return null.

```
var newproductionOrder = await _productionOrderRepository.CreateProductionOrder(newProduct,productionOrder);

if (newproductionOrder != null)
{
    await _productionOrderRepository.UpdateCounter();
    await _productRepository.UpdateCounter();
    return newproductionOrder;
}
throw new Exception("Failed to Create ProductionOrder");
```

my test code snippet

```cs
A.CallTo(() => fakePORepository.CreateProductionOrder(
        allProducts[0], invalidProductionOrder))
    .Returns(nullProductionOrder);
```

the null productionOrder was created by doing below

```cs
public static ProductionOrderDto? CreateNullProductionOrderDto()
{
    return null;
}
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Tried using return lazily to specify a customized way of return null. Yet it still returns the fakeiteasy object and my if statement runs while it doesn't have to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing how the types of `allProducts[0]` and  `invalidProductionOrder` are defined, it's impossible to say. But your code generally looks good, so the most likely explanation is that the `Equals` methods are reference-based, not value-based, and the objects being passed in are not exactly the same instance that you're using to configure the fake.

See [Argument constraints - Matching values exactly](https://fakeiteasy.github.io/docs/8.1.0/argument-constraints/#matching-values-exactly) for an explanation of FakeItEasy's "default" argument comparison.

Debug through. Verify whether the `Equals` methods would return true for each argument.

Comment: The  `allProducts[0]` and ` invalidProductionOrder` are the valid object typespassed as params to the method. I will try your suggestions thanks.

Comment: Ha. Ignoring the parameters seem to work. Even though i am using the same variables in my method calls so how come. But anyway thanks. This was helpful.